# Какую транзакцию запустить, чтобы чтение данных блокировало таблицы на обновление?

Tags: sql

Какую транзакцию запустить, чтобы чтение данных блокировало таблицы на обновление?

Comment: транзакции

Comment: субд укажите, ответ зависит от реализации субд.

Answer (score 1):

Блокировка должна накладываться при стандартных настройках.
Как раз наоборот, если вы не хотите, чтобы блокировки накладывались, используются хинты типа NOLOCK (SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

Если Oracle, то это [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/for_update.php).

Answer (score 0):

Если MySQL то:

```
SELECT HIGH_PRIORITY ...
```

Из документации:

> HIGH_PRIORITY gives the SELECT higher
> priority than a statement that updates
> a table.